# How to get jQuery UI autocomplete and Zurb Foundation to work together with Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline, modernizr, zurb-foundation

Ive seen this question [Zurb Foundation conflicts with jQuery UI autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666114/zurb-foundation-conflicts-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete), but I was hoping for some in-detail instructions on how best to configure with the rails asset pipeline, what to require from the gems, etc. One answer includes

> So i have removed the jQuery Code from foundation.min.js and added
>   Google CDN for jQuery.

But I'm not sure how I'd do that, or if that is even the best way. The problem is that `$.fn.autocomplete` is undefined.

**Question:**
How can I have access to a working jQuery, Modernizr, Zurb Foundation elements, and jQuery UI autocomplete all in the same page?

---

Right now I use the following gems:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'modernizr'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
```

And here is my `application.js` manifest file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.textchange
//= require foundation
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require_tree .
```

I've read that Zurb Foundation includes Modernizr and jQuery, so not sure if the jquery require is necessary. Thanks in advance for any and all tips

Comment: Summary : do you like to include jQuery by CDN or you would like to be sure you need it with Zurb?

Comment: Can you show the js files called and the order?